# Can I make window title bar merge with menu app in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, panel

I just migrated from Windows to Xubuntu with XFCE. After using it for a while, there was something that stuck like the title bar didn't blend with the app menu, unlike when using Windows where the title bar blends with the app menu along with the minimize, maximize buttons and close.

1. Title bar in xubuntu:

   [image: title bar in xubuntu]
2. Title bar in windows:

   [image: title bar in windows]

Can I make the title bar blend with the app menu and buttons like in Windows?

Comment: One quick suggestion - blend VS Code to match with XFCE instead.

Comment: almost all the results tell to add gnome tweak extensions, I have followed the steps but stopped when gnome shell
https://i.imgur.com/nPCDRSX.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the link below, in "Settings", search for window.titleBarStyle and set it to from native.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/65608

Comment: thanks you very much. this is work. 

https://i.imgur.com/Pd68crQ.png

but, can i want to change all title bar like vs code?

Comment: Not all apps use CSD so this cant be done to all apps.

Comment: oh okay thanks for your explanation,